# Consolidate Primary Keys into one

Tags: php, sql, postgresql-8.4

First off my database is Postgres version 8.4 and my web application is written in PHP.

Alright so I have a table setup in postgres with the following columns:

```
TABLE string 
idstring serial (primary key)
english character varying(128)
```

I have ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE for all foreign keys to idstring.  I want to be able to select several idstring's through a web application and consolidate them all into one new row and update ALL references to all of the selected idstring's to my new idstring and then remove all of the selected idstrings from the string table.

For example The table has the following data before the consolidation:

```
idstring | english
------------------
1        | eng1
2        | eng2
3        | eng3
```

I then select idstring 1 and 2 and want to consolidate them into a new row with english value of 'NEW'.  The table should now look like:

```
idstring | english
------------------
3        | eng3
4        | NEW
```

Before deleting the idstrings 1 and 2, I want to update all references to them to reference idstring 4. How can I do this?  Currently I have several queries updating each reference to idstrings 1 and 2 to idstring 4 manually.  I appreciate any input and hope I explained my intentions well enough.

Comment: So have you thought about how you may sequence out a set of queries to do what you want?  Are you considering using transactions?

Comment: I did not know about transactions... I'll look more into that.  I take it there is no way to do this other then a set of queries manually updating each foreign key referencing the idstring column?

Comment: `update yourtable set idstring=4, english=NEW where idstring in (1,2)`

Comment: You can't do that update without creating duplicate primary keys. Seems like transaction is the way to go.